# IHttpContextAccessor returns null Username claims in AspNetCore 5 API Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I have some Api Controllers in my AspNetCore 5 web application containing some methods which are available to unauthenticated users and some of them are only available for authorized users.

Assume that there is a ReviewController which all users can add review, but if the user is authenticated, we should fill username field.

Let's say in **TestController**:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]/")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public TestController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string TestA()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public string TestB()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

*The only difference between two methods is `Authorize` attribute.*

I setup **JwtBearer** authentication in the application with below setup.

**ConfigureServices:**

```
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var jwtConfig = new JwtConfig
        {
            Secret = "some secrets!",
            Audience = "http://localhost:5000",
            Expires = 600,
            Issuer = "http://localhost:5000"
        };

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtConfig.Secret);
            jwt.SaveToken = true;
            jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, 
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                SaveSigninToken = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtConfig.Audience,
                ValidIssuer = jwtConfig.Issuer
            };
        });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddDataAnnotations()
            .AddApiExplorer()
            .AddFormatterMappings()
            .AddCors();
    }
```

**And Configure:**

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {          
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

When I am calling `TestB` it returns the logged in username. But, when I am calling `TestA` it returns null.

Why `IHttpContextAccessor`'s user claims are not loaded and how can I access to `IHttpContextAccessor`'s username and user claims in any condition? Assume that I am using that in other layers than controllers.

Comment: Could you try invoking `TestB` after changing `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` into `[Authorize]`?

Comment: @MichalRosenbaum I did and it responds HTTP 401 (unauthorized) when I call `TestB`.

Comment: your words are conflicting, if you call `TestB` and it returns `401`, how did you know that *it returns the logged in username* (as posted in your question)? Actually I think the authentication is failed in both cases (calling `TestA` and `TestB`). But `TestB` has `AuthorizeAttribute`, the access will be short-circuited and returned with `401`. Now the issue may be harder, you need to examine your request to see if it contains valid credentials info, debugging into the source code may be needed, it really depends on your actual code.

Comment: @KingKing Michal asked me if I tried to change `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` into `[Authorize]` in the posted code or not, and I replied that. It means that `TestB` in the posted code returns logged in username.

Comment: not sure how it's different after that change, your default auth scheme is `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` so using just `[Authorize]` should be the same as `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` - I'm feeling confused now. They are different only in case you don't use authentication middleware (by `UseAuthentication`).